# Why does Moshi return a nullable object when parsing json with fromJson?

Tags: kotlin, moshi

It is probably just me using it wrong as I am new to Kotlin and Moshi.

`data class InitialAppResult(val status: Int, val message: String, val baseprm: String)`

```
val moshi = Moshi.Builder().add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory()).build()  
val adapter = moshi.adapter(InitialAppResult::class.java)
val fromJson = adapter.fromJson(result.get())
```

How come the fromJson is can be null and requires a !! or ?. For example: `fromJson!!.baseprm`

If the parsing fails with a required field missing it just throws an exception in my case. So how can it parse an "invalid" JSON response and not fail, i.e return null?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Moshi is a library implemented in Java, while your code is written in Kotlin. Quoting from the documentation, section "[Calling Java code from Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types)":

> Any reference in Java may be null, which makes Kotlin's requirements of strict null-safety impractical for objects coming from Java.

This means that any object coming from Java will be nullable by default.
However, if you declare a variable to have a non-nullable type, Kotlin will "cast" it automatically:

> When a platform value [i.e., a Java object in this case] is assigned to a Kotlin variable, we can rely on type inference (the variable will have an inferred platform type then, as item has in the example above), or we can choose the type that we expect (both nullable and non-null types are allowed).

Here's an example (again from the documentation linked above), where `item` is a Java object:

```
val nullable: String? = item // allowed, always works
val notNull: String = item // allowed, may fail at runtime
```

Hence, in your case you can force the object to be non-nullable by typing:

```
val fromJson: InitialAppResult = adapter.fromJson(result.get())
```

### Edit

In this case, all the `fromJson` methods are defined as `@Nullable` (as `null` is a valid JSON value), meaning that the result can be `null`, so the inferred type is nullable.  The same applies with `@NotNull`. So these annotations are very useful in case of interoperability between Java and Kotlin.

In other cases, where the `@Nullable` or `@NotNull` annotations are missing, what said above about explicitly adding the value to a variable is true.

### Edit 21/07/2020

> Why does `fromJson` is marked as `@Nullable`?

The reason is that `null` is a valid JSON value. The following examples are all valid JSON strings:

- `null`
- `{ "key": null }`

Hence, `JsonAdapter` needs to be able to deal with `null` values. For instance, here's how the built-in [`ObjectJsonAdapter`](https://github.com/square/moshi/blob/7f2630daee8bac295ac15cf82b8db9dab9c06622/moshi/src/main/java/com/squareup/moshi/StandardJsonAdapters.java#L313) deals with `null`s:

```
@Override public Object fromJson(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
    ...
    case NULL:
      return reader.nextNull();
}
```

That relies on `nextNull`, whose [documentation](https://square.github.io/moshi/1.x/moshi/com/squareup/moshi/JsonReader.html#nextNull--) says:

> Consumes the next token from the JSON stream and asserts that it is a literal null. Returns null.

Comment: Thank you, assumed it was due to Moshi being written in Java. I was also looking for more elegant way to state that it won't be null, as you did in the last line.

Comment: This doesn't explain why `fromJson` is marked with `@Nullable`. When can it return a `null`?

Comment: @user3681304 I assume that's because `null` is a valid JSON value

Comment: @user3681304 I've edited my answer with more details on why and how `null` can be returned. Hope that helps